# Deploy custom widget with in salesforce

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, widget

I'm currently working on a project where I need to display a custom widget within the salesforce application. I've custom javascript code that will help me to display the widget as a button.
But I'm wondering how to display the widget for the complete application which means If I navigate to accounts or any screen that button needs to be displayed everywhere. Please guide me on the better way to achieve this.

My button will display like this.
[image]

Custom Js code:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this needs a custom solution or at the best implementing a custom component built just to house the widget. It depends on what you're trying to accomplish.
Can we get some more info, where and how do you intend to use it when you say 'accross the application'. Was the app made using Lightning app builder or a custom Aura/LWC based app?

There are several possible places where you need the widget:

1. Login screen flow or welcome flows.
2. Record Detail pages
3. List view of records
4. Custom Aura/LWC pages if any.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Utility Bar](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/use_config_for_utility_bar) component, then add it to your [Lightning Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dev_apps_lightning_utilities.htm&type=5). The Utility Bar is generally available in most places in Lightning, so it should probably serve your purposes just fine. As a bonus, such components are context-sensitive, so you can determine what record or page they are looking at if you want to provide context-sensitive help.